# pandas dataframe how to do "elementwise" concatenation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes `A,B` with identical shape, index and column. Each element of `A` is a `np.ndarray` with shape `(n,1)`, and each element of `B` is a float value. Now I want to *efficiently* append `B` elementwise to `A`. A minimal example:

```
index = ['fst', 'scd']

column = ['a','b']

A
Out[23]: 
          a       b
fst  [1, 2]  [1, 4]
scd  [3, 4]  [3, 2]

B
Out[24]: 
            a         b
fst  0.392414  0.641136
scd  0.264117  1.644251

resulting_df = pd.DataFrame([[np.append(A.loc[i,j], B.loc[i,j]) for i in index] for j in column], columns=column, index=index)

resulting_df
Out[27]: 
                              a                           b
fst  [1.0, 2.0, 0.392414377685]  [3.0, 4.0, 0.264117463613]
scd  [1.0, 4.0, 0.641136433253]   [3.0, 2.0, 1.64425062851]
```

Is there something similar to [`pd.DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) that can operate elementwise between two instead of just one pandas dataframe?

Comment: Input and expected output if possible

Comment: @Bharathshetty added. Thanks.

Comment: Curious, what is the useuse for storing data like this? DataFrames are best for mxn scalars, otherwie you've Panel option as well

Comment: @Zero for financial analysis purpose: index is date, column is stock pool and I need to perform cross-sectional regressions with data in `A` and `B` combined as explanatory variables.

Comment: I think your output is wrong. `a`  of `scd` should be `[3.0, 4.0, 0.264117463613]` na

Comment: @Bharathshetty oh yeah. It's missing a transpose.

Comment: So my first thought was to use a generator to yield from `df2.values.flatten()`, to do `df.applymap(lambda x: x.append(next(mgen))` .. this fails due to `apply` functionality explicitly iterating over the first column twice. I am not sure whether there is an actually efficient way to do this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the elements in df2 to list using applymap and then just ordinary addition to combine the list i.e

```
index = ['fst', 'scd']

column = ['a','b']


A = pd.DataFrame([[[1, 2],[1, 4]],[[3, 4],[3, 2]]],index,column)
B = pd.DataFrame([[0.392414,0.264117],[ 0.641136 , 1.644251]],index,column)
```

**Option 1** :

```
n =  B.applymap(lambda y: [y])
ndf = A.apply(lambda x : x+n[x.name])
```

**Option 2** :
using `pd.concat` to know how this works check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583382/how-to-flatten-rows-having-similar-index-in-pandas) i.e

```
pd.concat([A,B]).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda g: pd.Series({i: np.hstack(g[i].values) for i in A.columns}))
```

To make you current method give correct output shift the loops i.e

```
pd.DataFrame([[np.append(A.loc[i,j], B.loc[i,j]) for j in A.columns] for i in A.index], columns=A.columns, index=A.index)
```

Output:

```
                       a                     b
fst  [1.0, 2.0, 0.392414]  [1.0, 4.0, 0.264117]
scd  [3.0, 4.0, 0.641136]  [3.0, 2.0, 1.644251]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if it would be more efficient than two for loops, though.

Comment: So sorry I din't try ur solution in the beginning will come up with something soon

Comment: no worries. Perhaps such complexity couldn't be mitigated. I posted this question mainly to search for existing wheels which hopefully might be more efficient than if we implement our own.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
>>> A + B.applymap(lambda x : [x])
                    a                 b
fst  [1, 2, 0.392414]  [1, 4, 0.264117]
scd  [3, 4, 0.641136]  [3, 2, 1.644251]
```