# How to flatten rows having similar index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.array([5,6]),6,np.array([8,10]),7],'b':[np.array([7,8]),9,np.array([15,10]),7]},index=[0,0,1,1])
```

```
        a         b
0   [5, 6]    [7, 8]
0        6         9
1  [8, 10]  [15, 10]
1        7         7
```

When I try `groupby`

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.flatten()))
```

```
         0         1  2  3
0   [5, 6]    [7, 8]  6  9
1  [8, 10]  [15, 10]  7  7
```

So how to use apply in such a way that I end up flattening the cells with similar index under the same column.

```
       a         b
0   [5, 6,6]    [7, 8,9]
1  [8, 10,7]  [15, 10,7]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for `numpy.hstack`. However, getting the output of a groupby into a dataframe is always a bit tricky when the values are multidimensional. Fitting things into a series usually works:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda g: pd.Series({
    'a': np.hstack(g['a'].values), 
    'b': np.hstack(g['b'].values)
}))
```

Of course, enumerating the dictionary would be nicer...

For `n` columns a dict comprehension would be better i.e

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda g: pd.Series({i: np.hstack(g[i].values) for i in df.columns}))
```

Comment: IanS you dont believe me I was so close.

Comment: I believe you :)